# Play Framework: Cannot find symbol "async"

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) and I am trying to make an HTTP request using the built in `WS` support. Whenever I try and make this HTTP request in a controller I get this error

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

for the code

```
public static Result foo(){
    return async(//ERROR ON THIS LINE FOR `async()`
        WS.url(GoogleStrategy.getTokenUrl).post(getTokenUrlParams).map(
            new F.Function<WSResponse, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object apply(WSResponse wsResponse) throws Throwable {
                        return ok(wsResponse.asJson());
                    }
            }
        )
    );
}
```

This is odd because in all of the examples shown in the documentation, this seams to be the correct way to do what I wish to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost certainly looking at an old version of the documentation.  `async()` is no longer needed.

The current version: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync

```
public static Promise<Result> foo(){
  return WS.url(GoogleStrategy.getTokenUrl).post(getTokenUrlParams).map(
    new F.Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
      @Override
      public Object apply(WSResponse wsResponse) throws Throwable {
        return ok(wsResponse.asJson());
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Note that to include `Promise<Result>` as the return type I had to change it to `F.Promise<Result>` if that helps...

Comment: Ryan, change `new F.Function<WSResponse, Object>()` to `new F.Function<WSResponse, Result>()`(`Object' -> `Result`) and I will accept your answer. Was almost correct, just a simple type error.

Comment: Okay, I made the change.